# Fix Message : Creating Party message How to do it

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Quickfix : FIX Message

I am new to fix
I need to create FIX message with below party info,
453 is repeat group

```
Party          - 453
Party/@ID      - 448
Party/@Src     - 447
Party/Pty/@R       - 452

Party/Sub      - 802
Party/Sub/@ID  - 523
Party/Sub/@Typ - 803
```

FIX version 4.4

Comment: Have you gone over the [repeating groups example](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.4/usage/repeating_groups.html) given in the QuickFIX/J FAQ?

Answer (score 4):

For example, for a new order single:

```java
NewOrderSingle.NoPartyIDs.NoPartySubIDs subID = new NewOrderSingle.NoPartyIDs.NoPartySubIDs();
subID.set(new PartySubID("Sub ID"));
subID.set(new PartySubIDType(PartySubIDType.EMAIL_ADDRESS));

NewOrderSingle.NoPartyIDs parties = new NewOrderSingle.NoPartyIDs();
parties.set(new PartyID("Party ID"));
parties.set(new PartyIDSource(PartyIDSource.MIC));
parties.set(new PartyRole(PartyRole.AGENT));
parties.addGroup(subID);

NewOrderSingle order = new NewOrderSingle();
order.addGroup(parties);
```